# check data reader null or not in while condition

Tags: vb.net

i have a query like this:

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim str As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Location_tbl.LocName, Location_tbl.Locid FROM Transaction_tbl"
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, con.connect)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
               ChkdLST.Visible = True
                ChkdLST.Items.Add(dr("LocName"))
            End While
            dr.Close()
            con.disconnect()
```

if reader contains any data then only i want to make chkdlst visible..so i want to check my datareader is null or not in the stage of  `While dr.Read`   if contains data then should visible else i have to make  ChkdLST.Visible = false..so how i can check `while dr.read` contains data or not

Comment: I would think that would work (besides the syntax error).  Do you set `ChkdLST.Visible = False` anywhere?

Comment: No sir..i never set ChkdLST.Visible = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data reader won't be null even if it returns no rows.  You probably want:

```
If dr.HasRows() Then
     'Code
 End If
```

Also your loop will never execute if your reader has no rows, so if you want to do special logic when the reader returns no rows, make sure you put it outside the `Read()` loop.